# Twitter Api showing Error 404

Tags: java, android, twitter

I want to get user tweets with http request to twitter api.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json");
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET"); //same error with POST
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am getting error 404. If I change version from 1.1 to 1 the it gives me error 410.
I have already created my account in developer site and have generated all of my tokens and keys.
**can Anybody tell me how to authenticate to twitter?**

**NOTE**:I am able to sign up with fabric sdk.

Regards.

Comment: I think request is `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: getting same error on both of them whether I use *GET* or *POST*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather using plane old URL class i would recomend to use any standard API to communicate with twitter like  http://twitter4j.org/

Code sample to check timeline

```
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
    System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");
    for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" + status.getText());
    }
```

To check other users time line :

```
Twitter unauthenticatedTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
//First param of Paging() is the page number, second is the number per page (this is capped around 200 I think.
Paging paging = new Paging(1, 100);
List<Status> statuses = unauthenticatedTwitter.getUserTimeline("ameyjadiye",paging);
```

Comment: can you tell me where to put this and what I have to import to make it work

Comment: check link given in my answer, either you have to put maven dependency in your project or download jar and add in your class path, more sample code is given on same site.

Comment: did you added twitter4j jar in your classpath? it will be resolved if you have added.

Comment: I tried your way but after adding twitter4j to my classpath its still giving the error. Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is full code Twitter.

https://github.com/shivagss/AndroidTwitterClient

Hope. It will help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are different libraries to get Twitter Tweets like:

1.[Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) Library

2. [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) by Twitter: fabric.io

If you are using Android studio then it has Android Studio Plugin which will configure easily Twitter.

Hope this help.

Comment: i know I can do it with FABRIC see my question. But what TO do for getting tweets?

Comment: Do you working on Android Studio? if yes then Did you setup Fabric in Android Studio?

Comment: DID you read this in my question *NOTE:I am able to sign up with fabric sdk.*